# Special characters not rendered correctly when changing from git_book to bs4_book in bookdown

Tags: r, utf-8, r-markdown, bookdown

I am working on a book using `bookdown` in Rstudio that was being rendered in `git_book` format, but after changing to `bs4_book` format all the Latin characters and even the apostrophe in English are not rendered correctly anymore (see image below). You can see the current live version in [this page](https://povcalnet-team.github.io/Povcalnet_internal_guidelines/) and the repository [here](https://github.com/PovcalNet-Team/Povcalnet_internal_guidelines).
[image]

I installed this version of bookdown, `remotes::install_github("rstudio/bookdown#1027")` based on [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1015) in Github, and also installed `bslib` like this, `remotes::install_github("rstudio/bslib")`

When I render the book in `bs4_book` I got the following messages that I did not get before with git_book,

```r
#> Tweaking docs/index.html
#> Tweaking docs/intro.html
#> Tweaking docs/folder-strcutures.html
#> Tweaking docs/collaboration-in-git.html
#> Tweaking docs/stata-github.html
#> Tweaking docs/intro-povcal.html
#> Tweaking docs/prepare.html
#> Tweaking docs/lis-data.html
#> Tweaking docs/primus.html

#> Warning messages:
#> 1: In parse(text = text, keep.source = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") :
#>   integer literal 02.L contains unnecessary decimal point
#> 2: In parse(text = text, keep.source = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") :
#>   integer literal 00.L contains unnecessary decimal point
#> 3: In parse(text = text, keep.source = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") :
#>   integer literal 02.L contains unnecessary decimal point
#> 4: In parse(text = text, keep.source = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") :
#>   integer literal 02.L contains unnecessary decimal point
#> 5: In parse(text = text, keep.source = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") :
#>   integer literal 00.L contains unnecessary decimal point
#> 6: In parse(text = text, keep.source = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") :
#>   integer literal 03.L contains unnecessary decimal point
```

You can see my session info below,

Thank you so much for your help. Best,

```r
sessioninfo::platform_info()
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       America/New_York            
#>  date     2020-12-20
Sys.getlocale()
#> [1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
stringi::stri_locale_info()
#> $Language
#> [1] "en"
#> 
#> $Country
#> [1] "US"
#> 
#> $Variant
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> $Name
#> [1] "en_US"
```

Comment: Looks like double [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). For Instance, `AndrÃ©s CastaÃ±eda` is `1252` appearance of UTF-8 encoded `Andrés Castañeda`. Warnings about integer literal are unclear for me. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. While trying to create a replicable example as suggested by @JosefZ, I literally copied and pasted from the original repo the minimum necessary files to create a workable version of the document into a different folder. Thus, I did not copy the output folder (which in this case is "docs"). By doing this the problem was gone. So, I deleted the output folder in the original repo and rebuilt the whole book again. This solved the problem and now it is rendering correctly.

**Bottom line:** When switching from `git_book` to `bs4_book`, make sure to delete the output folder (where the html files go), and rebuild the whole thing.

Thanks.
Best,

Comment: FWIW you can use `bookdown::clean_book()` to clean the bookdown result and start fresh before rebuilding a book !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this question, I had a similar one!

I'm afraid for me, the problem was not simply solved by deleting the `docs` folder where I had my `html` files.

This [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1015) resolved it for me though.

The solution was to install the `bookdown` version from Pull Request #1027 where Hadley fixed this.

```r
remotes::install_github("rstudio/bookdown#1027")
```

I presume this will be merged to the main branch soon, but for now, this did it for me.